# jQuery Replace whitespace by «-» Not working with <input type="email" />

Tags: jquery, regex, input, replace, whitespace

I have problem for replace whitespace by «-» in  no working. Why?

But ein type="text" is working

My Code HTML is simple:

```
<input type="text" class="demo" placeholder="type=text" /><br /><br />
<input type="email" class="demo" placeholder="type=email" />
```

My Code jQuery:

```
$(document).on("keyup",".demo",function(e) {
            
        
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s+$/g, "-"));

});
```

My jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6qo973vm/11/

Solutions?

Comment: It seems the `$(this).val()` value is trimmed automatically and the function does not "see" the trailing whitespace chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how do I solve it?

Comment: Try to change regexp from `/\s+$/g` to `/\s/g`. But in Chrome  it will work only after next character is entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for an input type email the value text returned is always trimmed you can replace the final space with the desired char.

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/poy96hsm/1/)

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".demo", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {  // in case of space...
        if (this.value.indexOf(' ') != -1) { // if the space is inside string
            this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
        } else {  // for type = email: the space is at the end: add a final char.....
            this.value = this.value + '-';
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>Replace whitespace by «-» Not workin in input type email</h1>
<input type="text" class="demo" placeholder="type=text"/><br/><br/>
<input type="email" class="demo" placeholder="type=email"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm yet to really investigate why such an input box behaves that way. While debugging,I also noticed that `event.target.value` is already trimmed before calling `.val()`. However, checkout the following snippet maybe you might see something I'm yet to discover. There is a delay that might need fixing too.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".demo", function(e) {
  if (this.id === "email") {
    document.getElementById("email").value = document.getElementById("email").value.replace(" ", "-")
  } else {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s+$/g, "-"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Replace whitespace by «-» Not workin in input type email</h1>
<input type="text" class="demo" placeholder="type=text" /><br /><br />
<input type="email" id="email" class="demo" placeholder="type=email" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.